# Ruby Rails double :through Association with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has many :signups           
has_many :events, through => :signups

has many :interests             
has_many :events, through => :interests
```

How would I give users access to events in two different ways? If I call `user.find(3).events` I will get both interested events and signed up events. I have a table of events and I have a separate model to store info for interests and signups.

I want to be able to call users and get their interested event or there signed up events but with separate calls. I dont want a joined object.

Comment: you can write scope where in one scope you will only select sign_up_ events column and in the other interests_events_column. You can not declare a model like in your code as it will create ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :interesting_events, :class_name => "Event", :through => :interests
```

Does this work>
Apologies for not not testing it out myself; the set up is a little more involved.